# Facing issue with creating one to one mapping in ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I want to do one to one mapping with servers from  3 arrays and arrays belong to different region in ruby. For example:

```rb
array1 = ['server1', 'server2']
array2 = ['server3', 'server4', 'server5']
array3 = ['server6', 'server7', 'server8']
```

Here in my case length of `array2` and `array3` will be always same. I want to use this in cookbook to execute on a server where I want to make a one-to-one mapping with `array2` and `array3` and search only for that particular server.

For example if I am executing this on server7 then it will return server4 and server7 only from one to one mapping and always pick first value from `array1`.

I am using this logic to make one to one mapping:

```
array1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
array2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
array1.zip(array2)
```

But not able to parse with hostname where my cookbook is executing.

Comment: What if you are executing on server4? What about server1?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean "not able to parse with hostname where my cookbook is executing"?

Comment: If i am executing in server4 also it needs to give me server4 and server7

Comment: I want only that one to one mapping which matches to hostname where i am executing my code for example if it is in server4 then (server4, server7) same index servers from array2 and array3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most of the way using `zip` to build this data structure but with your implementation you can only look up the servers in *one* of the arrays - can't look up all the servers.

So I would recommend altering it using something like the following:

```
servers_map = array2.zip(array3).to_h.tap do |hsh|
  hsh.merge!(hsh.invert)
end
```

This will give you the following:

```
{"server3"=>"server6", "server4"=>"server7", "server5"=>"server8", "server6"=>"server3", "server7"=>"server4", "server8"=>"server5"}
```

If you had a variable `current_server` and wanted to get a `[serverA, serverB]` array as a result, you could just use:

```
[current_server, servers_map[current_server]]
```